Import and export inventory
Please tell me what Dax I use to calculate end_stock and start_stock. I am having problems transferring the previous day's end inventory to the next day's start inventory, keeping ID values, ​​and adding a new ID if there is more data input, dropping the old ID with end-of-day inventory value = 0. The initial data is available on December 31, 2023, and will be exported and imported in 2024.
I still have no solution to this problem.


could you pls provide some sample data ?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

So, we want to create a Start Inventory column. But the Start Inventory needs End Inventory.
I found two methods to find the End Inventory:
End Inventory Formula 1:
CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Import]),FILTER('Table',EARLIER('Table'[day])>='Table'[day]&&EARLIER('Table'[ID])='Table'[ID])) - CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Export]),FILTER('Table',EARLIER('Table'[day])>='Table'[day]&&EARLIER('Table'[ID])='Table'[ID]))

End Inventory Formula 2:
    VAR CurrentDay = 'Table'[day]
    VAR CurrentID = 'Table'[ID]
    VAR DaysRange = DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Day])
    
    VAR ImportSum = 
        SUMX(
            GENERATESERIES(1, DaysRange),
            LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Import], 'Table'[day], CurrentDay - [Value], 'Table'[ID], CurrentID)
        )
    
    VAR ExportSum = 
        SUMX(
            GENERATESERIES(1, DaysRange),
            LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Export], 'Table'[day], CurrentDay - [Value], 'Table'[ID], CurrentID)
        )
    
    RETURN
        (ImportSum - ExportSum) + 'Table'[Import] - 'Table'[Export]

You can you use either of the above to fine the End Inventory

And finally, now that we have End Inventory, we can create the Start Inventory easily.
Start Inventory Formula:
 LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[End stock Method],'Table'[Day],'Table'[Day]-1,
'Table'[ID],'Table'[ID])

Once you created Start Inventory, you can just create a Key column to exclude dropping the old ID with the end-of-day inventory.
I have attached snippets with explanation for End Inventory Formula 1 and Entire tables view.



